# How to plot a graph from 2 columns in a dataframe using plotnine?

Tags: python, r, ggplot2, plotnine

I am trying to understand how this works

Dataframe is "result"

Column in "result" is Time, Column1, Column2

I am able to plot only a single line from the Column1 from the code below:

```
(p9.ggplot(data=result,
           mapping=p9.aes(x='Time', y='Column1'))
+ p9.geom_point(alpha=0.5)
+ p9.scale_x_datetime(breaks=date_breaks('12 hour'))
)
```

How to write the code if I wanted it to include Column2? Means plot 2 lines in the chart?

Comment: As an R and ggplot2 user I'm not familiar with `plotnine`. But in ggplot2 something like `+ p9.geom_point(mapping=p9.aes(x='Time', y='Column2'), alpha=0.5)` would add a second geom_point layer with the y values given by Column2.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be working! But the thing is, both will be sharing the same y axis. It will be problematic in the vase where column 1 and 2 is not using the same units or having large difference range. Thanks anyway for the answer.

Comment: I see. Secondary axes are a bit tricky in ggplot2. In ggplot2 you could add a secondary y axis via the `sec.axis` argument of `scale_y_continuous`. However, I just had a look at the plotnine documentation and it looks like this feature has not been implemented in plotnine. ):

Comment: In that case, is there anything else that I could use to achieve it? Seaborn?

Answer (score 1):

Plotnine's current API (as of 2022-08-09) doesn't include a secondary axis, so this is not possible to do. It is a feature that has been requested several times though, and looks like it is in the roadmap for the next [major release](https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine/issues/551).

In any case, if you want to keep with the `ggplot2` style you will have to move to R and use the `sec.axis` of `scale_y_continous` (you can see several examples [here](https://r-graph-gallery.com/line-chart-dual-Y-axis-ggplot2.html).

If you want to stay in Python, you can just go directly to `matplotlib`, as secondary axes are supported using the `.twinx()` method. The working example for your case would be:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = result.plot(x='Date', y='Column1', color='blue', legend=False)
sec_axis = ax.twinx()
result.plot(x='Date', y='Column2', ax=sec_axis, color='red', legend=False)
ax.figure.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```py
(p9.ggplot(data=result.melt(id_vars = 'Time'),
           mapping=p9.aes(x='Time', y='value', color='variable', group = 'variable'))
+ p9.geom_point(alpha=0.5)
+ p9.scale_x_datetime(breaks=date_breaks('12 hour'))
)
```